# TCP packet segment python

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm handling TCP packets. This application acts as an sniffer and builds up SIP Packets. Some TCP SIP packets come fragmented hence I need to reassemble them.

What I do is that Initially I process first TCP connection using:

```
packet = s.recvfrom(sipLocatorConfig.NETWORK_MAX_SIZE)
```

After that I obtain the data and then if fragmented I get the rest but using `.recv`:

```
socket.recv(sipLocatorConfig.NETWORK_TCP_MAX_SIZE)
```

When I obtained the second fragment, I get garbled data at the beginning when using `.recv`, which I assume is the ETH, IP, TCP info:

```
M*?
M*?@{
QyE
```

How can I remove this ETH, IP and TCP header info and extract just the data from Packet?
Thanks

Comment: Side note: You should be printing your garbeldy gook in hex. Use `binascii.hexlify` on the packet data.

Comment: If you know how many bytes they take, you can just skip that amount of bytes from your data.

Comment: Thanks I was able to use that module, now I can see ETH, IP and TCP header info in HEX,  0a4d2ac000030a4d2acf407b0800
 4500033017bd40004006a9e8ac1f2e380c478f84
 81b013c4c30e71fbc8d7d65b8018073c794500000101080a09e2e0c893db873e, how can remove ETH, IP and TCP info from packet received using .recv function? Something similar like this: http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/

Comment: Bytes may vary from different packets.

Comment: I was able to obtain payload data by processing socket.recv() as string. socket.recvfrom() returns a tuple. Hence I just commented the line packet=packet[0] and works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the packet as:

- First 14 bytes is ethernet header
- Next 20 bytes is probably ip header
- similarly,from ip header, we can extract protocol we are using and
  finally see the protocol reference to parse data out of it

Eg. TCP connection packet comes as : `eth_header+IP_header+TCP_Header+payload(data)`
   Each header have their specific length and extracting informations out of the headers would require you to use struct modules in python (see struct.unpack("","")). Extracting header infos also would require knowledge of the structure of headers. Finally you can calculate the payload position and finally extract it.

Specifically, please see this [link](http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/) for more information. Hope this helps